# fork() call in c

Tags: c, fork

I have used fork() to create 2 different processes operating on 2 different address spaces.
Now, in parent process I need the value of a variable from child's address space or if the child process can modify the variable in parent's address space.
Is this possible?

Comment: so maybe you need threads rather then separate processes?

Comment: @PiotrekDe: `operating on 2 different address spaces`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, once you've forked, each process gets its *own* address space and you'll have to look into either:

- some form of IPC between the processes to access each others data (such as shared memory or message queues).
- some more lighweight variant of fork that allows sharing of data (including possibly threading).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have two processes, sharing data needs interprocess communication: file, pipe or shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean exchanging data between these two processes you can not. You can do it by system APIs like SharedMemory, Message Passing, Pipeline, Socket, ...

Answer (score 0):

As you have created two process using fork command Both Process will be in different address space so they will only communicate by IPC, message passing ,Piping , Shared Memory etc. otherwise one process can't access other process data as thay do have Process specific data
and similarly threads also have thread specific data